# Check installed packages + check effective deployement of packages [to detect problems caused by memory corruption]

Tags: linux, apt, corruption, checksum

My computer has a flawed memory stick for two years and I can't correct this (sticks aren't removable and computer cannot be changed : so it won't be the subject).

Sometimes a content is corrupted during installation. It might be :

1. A package **A** that becomes an **A'** package on disk ?

   - Isn't it always checked by `apt` commands ?
   - I don't know if their is really a manner a **A** package could be written eventually corrupted on disk.

I think my problems start on next point :

2. At deployment / decompression time, the files extracted and put at work in due folders take a hit and files **a.o** or **b.lib** become **a'.o** and **b'.lib** while **c**, **d**, **e** files and others are ok.

Problems comes more often if I install a rather big thing : `GNOME` or `linux-image-amd64` : my computer has chances to create few incorrect things from their contents.

To figure the whole trouble better, installing a whole `Debian 10` on a VM succeed at first attempt only one time on two. Suspend a VM has a chance to see it unable to be restored, due to a CRC check problem.

You can though : "*If you guess there's a problem, reinstall the tool you believe is wrong !*", but reinstalling `GNOME`, for example, would leave an installation that has - let's say - 10 errors dispatched everywhere to another of 8 to 12 put elsewhere...

I have to track them  more precisely to correct my troubles. Among these all my deployments find those who are wrongly done among the binaries (and files accompanying them). And then discover what package they are coming from to download it again (if necessary) and reinstall specifically and only the ones needed.

### My needs

1. Check if `.deb` or `.zip` or `.tar` - packages in general - need to be downloaded again because they are corrupted.

   Find if an **A.deb** package has a correct checksum on my disk compared to it's genuine source.
2. The most important : check if the decompressed files coming from it stayed correct on disk.

   if **a1.o**, **a2.txt**, **a3.lib**... coming from it have a good content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `apt` will check `.deb` packages against their published checksums, and re-download them if necessary (or fail if it can’t). In general, most package or archive corruption will cause decompression to fail anyway; for non-`.deb` archives you can also look for checksums alongside them from wherever you downloaded them.
2. You can use `debsums`, either one package at a time, or to check the system in its entirety: `debsums -c` will report all the files which don’t match the checksums stored in the package from which they came.

Comment: Does `debsums` check each single file inside a package (`.txt`, `.o`, `.lib`, `.css`, `.js` files inside), ...against the files installed ? For the  `gnome-shell` package, in example, will it check all the 80 files it contains against each corresponding file found on my system or will it only do a superficial control that `gnome-shell.deb` md5 of the genuine `Debian` = `gnome-shell.deb` md5 on my disk ?

Comment: `debsums` checks all the files extracted from the package, not the package itself (which you might not even have any more). For `gnome-shell`, it will check all 40 files, 41 if you run `debsums -a` (which also checks configuration files, which might have been changed locally). (At least in Debian 10, `gnome-shell` ships 41 files.)